# How to check if string contains list value and separately if contains but with other value

Tags: c#, regex, string, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to  define if string contains/does not contains list value and if contains but with other value.

If I have input string:

```
string inputString = "it was one";
```

and I want find specific value for condition:

```
var numbList = new List<string> {"zero", "one", "two"}; 

if (!numbList.Any(inputString.Contains)) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("string does not contains list value");                                           
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("string contains list value"); 
}
```

But not sure what is a proper way if I want to know also about third condition, if string contains value but also contains other words.

For string: `inputString = "it was one";` desired result should be:

```
 Console.WriteLine("string contains list value and other words");
```

for string: `inputString = "one";`

```
 Console.WriteLine("string contains list value");
```

and for: `inputString = "it was";`

```
 Console.WriteLine( "string does not contains list value");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
if (inputString.Split(new string[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).All(x => numbList.Contains(x)))
{
    opDisplay="string contains list value";
}
else if (numbList.Any(x => inputString.Contains(x)))
{
    opDisplay = "string contains list value and other words";
}
else
{
    opDisplay = "string does not contains list value";
}
```

You can try an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZm4yt)

Comment: if there are multiple spaces between each word in the `inputString` then it returns else if part. for example => **zero    one two**. removing extra ones could handle it. (SO comment input area removes extra ones already. lol )

Comment: if their are additional spaces in between words means, you can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to exclude those empty spaces, see the updates in the post

Comment: @un-lucky Hello, seems like it is answer, but not sure if I don't use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries what is reasult for "it     was    one"?

Comment: When we performs split, it will split based on single space so, if their is more number of spaces then it results empty items in the collections. to avoid that we use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: @un-lucky yes but no needed in my case, I allow only one space between words in input string

Answer (score 1):

why not use below code? i can not think of one condition where it fails.

```
            string inputString = "it was one ";
            var numbList = new List<string> { "zero", "one", "two" };
            if (numbList.Any(x => inputString.Contains(x)))
            {
                if (numbList.Any(x => inputString.Trim().StartsWith(x) && inputString.Trim().EndsWith(x)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("string contains list value");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("string contains list value and other words");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string does not contains list value");
            }
```

find the fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fprE4l)

Comment: hello, both ways are useful, in some cases this one can be more suitable, depends. Anyway both answers can be used